# SELECT query on string field that treat dash char "-" as a space

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which a VARCHAR(255) field could have "-" dahs char used as a blank space because it reports chemical compounds retrieved from external DBs. The same compounds could have been written without dash char(s) and a blank space instead of them or a subset of them. For instance, the compound "2-hydroxy-propionic acid" could have been written

1. "2-hydroxy propionic acid"
2. "2 hydroxy-propionic acid"
3. "2 hydroxy propionic acid"

All of them are proper writings and they refer to the same compound. Is there an elegant way to SELECT the stored field "2-hydroxy-propionic acid" if the search string is one of the other 3? That is just an example, the dash char could be just one or even more than 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) in order to replace any hyphens with spaces in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  MyTable
  WHERE (REPLACE(myField, '-', ' ') = REPLACE('2-hydroxy-propionic acid', '-', ' '));
```

This works because all hyphens in the source field are replaced by spaces, and the hyphens in the criteria are also replaced by spaces.

In this way, all the results will be returned regardless of where the hyphens are (or are not).

Output based on your example rows:

```
2-hydroxy-propionic acid
2-hydroxy propionic acid
2 hydroxy propionic acid
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bcopNuA6KRoPM4wY2sA85C/0) showing this in action.

Comment: simply extraordinary! Thank you!